# Best way to do rendering on Linux server with GPU but without a display?

Tags: debian, gpu, x-server, opengl

I have a rendering software, to be more specific, it's a Unity3D «game» that renders video (saving rendered frames).

Unfortunately Unity3D doesn't support «headless» rendering (it can run in headless mode, but in this case it doesn't render frames), so it needs an X server to create a window.

- I have a Debian Bullseye server with ~~Intel GPU (630)~~ NVidia GT1030 with proprietary driver
- I don't have any kind of display
- I can't plug anything like HDMI fake display device.
- It's performance-critical, so it must be rendered fully hardware-accelerated, so solutions like `xvfb` are not suitable.

And I also want to run it in Docker, and sometimes I need to see what's rendering right now with VNC for debugging purposes.

As I understand it, I need to:

1. Run an X server on the host machine, creating a virtual display
2. Share host's X server with a docker container, run my app and a VNC server there

Is it the best way to do that?

I've created a virtual display:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync    20.0 - 120.0
    VertRefresh  30.0 - 120.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce GT 1030"
    Option      "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP"
    Option      "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/EDID.bin"
    Option      "ConstrainCursor" "off"
    BusID       "PCI:01:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Device0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    Option      "TwinView" "0"
    Option      "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0"
    SubSection "Display"
            Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And started X:

```
sudo X :0 -config /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

It starts without any errors, but seems hung (doesn't react to Ctrl+C, and the only way to kill it is `kill -9 PID`).

`glxinfo` doesn't work:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 glxinfo
name of display: :0

X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  110
  Current serial number in output stream:  111
```

However, if I specify the display, `xrandr` shows its info:

```
$ xrandr -d :0
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02*   60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

X server log seems fine:

```
[   306.770] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   306.770] Build Operating System: linux Debian
[   306.770] Current Operating System: Linux home-server 5.10.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1 (2021-09-30) x86_64
[   306.770] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.10.0-9-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/home--server--vg-root ro quiet
[   306.770] Build Date: 13 April 2021  04:07:31PM
[   306.770] xorg-server 2:1.20.11-1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[   306.770] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[   306.770]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   306.770] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   306.770] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Nov 18 21:49:50 2021
[   306.770] (++) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   306.770] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[   306.770] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[   306.770] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[   306.770] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[   306.770] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[   306.770] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[   306.770] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   306.770] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   306.770] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   306.770] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   306.770] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   306.770]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   306.770] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   306.770]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   306.770] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   306.770]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   306.770] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1" does not exist.
[   306.770]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   306.770] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   306.770]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   306.770] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   306.770]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   306.770] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        built-ins
[   306.770] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   306.770] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[   306.770] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[   306.770] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[   306.770] (II) Loader magic: 0x562334c16e40
[   306.770] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   306.770]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   306.770]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[   306.770]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   306.770]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   306.771] (--) using VT number 3

[   306.771] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   306.771] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   306.772] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:1d01:1043:85f4 rev 161, Mem @ 0xa2000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00003000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   306.772] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   306.772] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   306.772] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   306.772]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[   306.772]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   306.772] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   306.772] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[   306.773] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   306.773]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[   306.773]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   306.773] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  470.86  Tue Oct 26 21:53:29 UTC 2021
[   306.773] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[   306.773] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   306.773] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   306.773] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   306.773] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   306.773]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[   306.773]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   306.773] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[   306.773] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[   306.773] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[   306.773] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   306.773]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[   306.773]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   306.773] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   306.773] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   306.773] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   306.773] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   306.773] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[   306.773] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   306.773] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   306.773] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
[   306.773] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP"
[   306.773] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/EDID.bin"
[   306.773] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MetaModes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0"
[   306.773] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[   306.773] (**) NVIDIA(0): ConnectedMonitor string: "DFP"
[   306.773] (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
[   306.773] (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
[   306.773] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglxserver_nvidia.so
[   306.777] (II) Module glxserver_nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   306.777]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[   306.777]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   306.777] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  470.86  Tue Oct 26 21:51:04 UTC 2021
[   306.777] (II) NVIDIA: The X server supports PRIME Render Offload.
[   306.953] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
[   306.953] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[   306.953] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[   306.953] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using ConnectedMonitor string "DFP-0".
[   306.953] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU NVIDIA GeForce GT 1030 (GP108-A) at PCI:1:0:0
[   306.953] (II) NVIDIA(0):     (GPU-0)
[   306.953] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[   306.953] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 86.08.0c.00.1a
[   306.953] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 4X
[   306.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2369M (DFP-0): connected
[   306.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2369M (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[   306.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2369M (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   306.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   306.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[   306.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[   306.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   306.954] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   306.958] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[   306.958] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:1280x1024+0+0"
[   306.958] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1280 x 1024
[   306.961] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (63, 89); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[   306.961] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[   306.961] (II) NVIDIA: Reserving 24576.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[   306.961] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[   306.963] (II) NVIDIA(0): ACPI: failed to connect to the ACPI event daemon; the daemon
[   306.963] (II) NVIDIA(0):     may not be running or the "AcpidSocketPath" X
[   306.963] (II) NVIDIA(0):     configuration option may not be set correctly.  When the
[   306.963] (II) NVIDIA(0):     ACPI event daemon is available, the NVIDIA X driver will
[   306.963] (II) NVIDIA(0):     try to use it to receive ACPI event notifications.  For
[   306.963] (II) NVIDIA(0):     details, please see the "ConnectToAcpid" and
[   306.963] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "AcpidSocketPath" X configuration options in Appendix B: X
[   306.963] (II) NVIDIA(0):     Config Options in the README.
[   306.975] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-0:1280x1024+0+0"
[   306.998] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[   306.998] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[   306.998] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   306.998] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[   306.998] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "TwinView" is not used
[   306.998] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   306.998] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   306.998] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   306.998] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   306.998] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[   306.998] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[   306.998] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[   306.998] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[   306.998] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[   306.999] (II) Initializing extension Present
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[   307.000] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   307.000] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[   307.000] (II) GLX: Another vendor is already registered for screen 0
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension NV-GLX
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension NV-CONTROL
[   307.000] (II) Initializing extension XINERAMA
[   307.019] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[   307.019] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.019] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.019] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[   307.019] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.019] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.019] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[   307.019] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.019] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.019] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event5)
[   307.019] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.019] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.019] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event6)
[   307.019] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.019] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.020] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event7)
[   307.020] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.020] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.020] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event8)
[   307.020] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.020] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.020] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event9)
[   307.020] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.020] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.020] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ASRock LED Controller (/dev/input/event0)
[   307.020] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.020] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.020] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ASRock LED Controller (/dev/input/js0)
[   307.020] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.020] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.021] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[   307.021] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.021] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.021] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event11)
[   307.021] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.021] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.021] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event12)
[   307.021] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.021] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.021] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event13)
[   307.021] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.021] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.021] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event14)
[   307.021] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.021] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   307.021] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event4)
[   307.021] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   307.021] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.739] (II) NVIDIA(0): ACPI: failed to connect to the ACPI event daemon; the daemon
[   390.739] (II) NVIDIA(0):     may not be running or the "AcpidSocketPath" X
[   390.739] (II) NVIDIA(0):     configuration option may not be set correctly.  When the
[   390.739] (II) NVIDIA(0):     ACPI event daemon is available, the NVIDIA X driver will
[   390.739] (II) NVIDIA(0):     try to use it to receive ACPI event notifications.  For
[   390.739] (II) NVIDIA(0):     details, please see the "ConnectToAcpid" and
[   390.739] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "AcpidSocketPath" X configuration options in Appendix B: X
[   390.739] (II) NVIDIA(0):     Config Options in the README.
[   390.739] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2369M (DFP-0): connected
[   390.739] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2369M (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[   390.739] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2369M (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   390.739] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   390.739] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[   390.739] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[   390.739] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   390.739] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   390.760] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-0:1280x1024+0+0"
[   390.781] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[   390.781] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[   390.781] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   390.781] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   390.781] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   390.781] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   390.781] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[   390.781] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[   390.781] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[   390.781] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[   390.781] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[   390.781] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[   390.781] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[   390.782] (II) Initializing extension Present
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[   390.783] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   390.783] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[   390.783] (II) GLX: Another vendor is already registered for screen 0
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension NV-GLX
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension NV-CONTROL
[   390.783] (II) Initializing extension XINERAMA
[   390.801] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[   390.801] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.801] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.801] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[   390.801] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.801] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.802] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[   390.802] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.802] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.802] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event5)
[   390.802] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.802] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.802] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event6)
[   390.802] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.802] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.802] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event7)
[   390.802] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.802] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.802] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event8)
[   390.802] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.802] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.803] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event9)
[   390.803] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.803] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.803] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ASRock LED Controller (/dev/input/event0)
[   390.803] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.803] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.803] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ASRock LED Controller (/dev/input/js0)
[   390.803] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.803] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.803] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[   390.803] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.803] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.803] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event11)
[   390.803] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.803] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.804] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event12)
[   390.804] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.804] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.804] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event13)
[   390.804] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.804] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.804] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event14)
[   390.804] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.804] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   390.804] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event4)
[   390.804] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   390.804] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Your X does not find a monitor on the GPU output so it deletes the screen from the configuraion. I have a similar problem with identical solution. I need a server, where users can access it via VNC. VNC needs a screen to run X on, even if there is no monitor attached. In my case I have nVidia card and nVidia driver, where I can use options "ConnectedMonitor", "UseDisplayDevice", and "CustomEDID". They make X believe there is a monitor attached to DVI output. I don't think these directives can be used for Intel driver.

Comment: @nobody thanks! Is it possible with gtx1030 and proprietary driver?

Comment: What outputs does GTX1030 have? Can you provide some specs? I find it easier to override D-SUB (VGA) or DVI outputs than HDMI or DisplayPort. I think it should work. In my experience it is easier to do it with older than newer GPUs.

Comment: @nobody it has DVI and HDMI ports. Can you please share your X config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My xorg.conf is like this

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Default Layout"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    Option         "XkbModel" "pc105"
    Option         "XkbLayout" "us"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync    20.0 - 120.0
    VertRefresh  30.0 - 120.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device0"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName   "Quadro FX 380"
    Option      "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP"
    Option      "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP-0"
    Option      "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/HPZ24nq.bin"
    BusID       "PCI:21:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Device0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    Option      "TwinView" "0"
    Option      "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0"
    SubSection "Display"
            Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The parameters that need changes for your computer are at least BusID, DFP, DFP-0, /etc/X11/HPZ24nq.bin.

I used edid file HPZ24nq.bin, which I got from some monitor. You will be able to set resolutions that are supported in an EDID file. You can get EDID file from monitor with `read-edid`.

BusID you can get with `lspci`. I am not sure if you need that.